# Convert h:m:s to hh:mm:ss in twig

Tags: twig, symfony-4.4

I have a little problem that I can't seem to solve and ask for your help please:
I have a branch variable which only contains hour, minute and second with no date. The problem is that its format is h: m: s is I would like to convert it to hh: mm: ss

My variable is : {{hours}} which contains for example: 1:5:7 is i would like to get a result 01:05:07.Can you help me please.

Note that I do not have access to the symfony4 controller because I am a designer thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [date](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html) anyways:

```
{% set hours = "1:2:3" %}
{{ hours|date('H:i:s') }}

#01:02:03
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine, but if the data comes from a dynamic array how do we do it? for example: var value = { "1": "1:0:0", "2": "1:5:4", "3": "3:6,10",.... };
{% for x in value %}
{% set hours = x %}
{{ hours|date('H:i:s') }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: just print `{{ x|date('H:i:s') }}` inside your for cycle.

Comment: I found my error, my variable contains a space which causes a bug, so I delete the space with {% set hours = value|replace({' ': ''}) %} is it works thank you very much, my problem is solved.